# Intrinsic support in gcc for s390/s390x architecture

Tags: c, gcc

For x86 architecture there is a rich support of intrinsic that can be used in C/C++. For s390 (Linux on system z) are there any intrinsics supported? I am specifically looking for intrinsics that would make the packed decimal instructions such as AP, CP, PACK available without having to resort to asm block.

Comment: Yes, there are headers with intrinsics. Look for them in your gcc installation?

Comment: I haven't been able to locate any in the s390x architecture /usr/lib/gcc/*. Usually the intrinsic headers will call a __builtin_ function, and I can't find any reference to builtin functions supported by gcc for s390x architecture.

Comment: I see `/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/include/s390intrin.h` but that seems to be only for transactional memory. Strange, the gcc sources also have a `vecintrin.h` with things like `vec_pack`, etc.